# Creating a custom contact form in Joomla, using code

Tags: joomla, contact-form

I developed my own custom Joomla contact us page for [this](http://www.dreamit-driveit.com/contact-us) website. However presently I have only pasted the HTML and CSS directly into the contact us article. As a result, whenever I make any changes to that article, I need to redo the CSS from scratch.

I was searching for any tutorials online which describes the way by which I could code this entire page up by editting the PHP files, but couldnt find any. Even I tried to go through each and every component and module, but it was no where to be seen

Any ideas on how I could get started

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really mean you want to code it manually I would just use the [component creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/). it won't take you more than 10 minutes to get your form ready :)

Also, you could do more advanced things like keeping track of the messages received by the same user, etc.

Hope it comes handy.

Comment: Thanks I did go through that site as well as another site http://joomlacomponentcreator.codelydia.com/index.php as well for creating joomla components. However I think this still does not match my needs, as I need to create this contact form from scratch, i.e. code
Any tips on which file I should edit or create in order to achieve this